# Android setError("error") not working in Textview

Tags: android, error-handling, popup, textview

We can set error in Edittext successfully but failed to set in textview. is there any problem??
i tried

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.df)).requestFocus();
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.df)).setSelected(true);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.df)).setError("akjshbd");
```

but i am not getting popup for error.

[image: Textview Error]

Comment: @Anis, this is written in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html, that setError(CharSequence error):
Sets the right-hand compound drawable of the TextView to the "error" icon and sets an error message that will be displayed in a popup when the TextView has focus.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Actually , you can use the setError for the textView and show its popup .

You just need to use the same style as of the EditText .

Simply add the next attribute for the textView in the xml :

```
style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
```

Comment: [nayoga0's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15954372/2209946) is much better than this.

Comment: @DavidLord In which way?

Comment: it pop up the keyboard :/

Comment: @AdeelTurk What do you mean?

Comment: i mean i resolved it by my self .. thanx for your concern :)

Comment: @AdeelTurk glad you did but could you share how you did so? It could help the community and people here could make it bug-free if there is an issue at all. :)

Comment: hey everyone i was in a rush at that time so couldnt find time to explain , i adopted the same solution given above but whenever you tao on field to look at the error message it activates the keyboard so for me putting android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true" 
 in textview worked like a charm .

Comment: @androiddeveloper and Sufiyan pardon me for the delay #PEACE ;)

Comment: @AdeelTurk Shouldn't it be the opposite? Meaning not focusable?

Comment: well! i want to show error when user tap on textview

Comment: yeah kind of!! thats why i said i sorted out my problem :)

Answer (score 100):

Default TextView is NOT focusable. So, you need to set **android:focusable="true"** and **android:focusableInTouchMode="true"**.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

And no need to set setSelected(true).

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.df)).requestFocus();
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.df)).setError("akjshbd");
```

Comment: I prefer this solution. Setting the style to @android:style/Widget.EditText is overkill and makes the TextView look like an EditText.

Comment: This solution is much cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a better solution, no doubt

Comment: it opens keyboard as well on click of textview

Answer (score 14):

This is the only you need to get expected setError behaviour on the TextView

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: simple enought, and doesn't show that annoyng editText style!

Comment: but it opens keyboard as well on click of textview

Answer (score 5):

Snippet:  you have to requestFocus(); a view to show the error.

```
    // Check for a valid email address.
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmail)) {
    mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
    focusView = mEmailView;
    cancel = true;
} else if (!mEmail.contains("@")) {
    mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
    focusView = mEmailView;
    cancel = true;
}

if (cancel) {
    // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
    // form field with an error.
    focusView.requestFocus();
} else {
    // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
    // perform the user login attempt.
    // showProgress(true);
    // mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
    // mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(mEmail, mPassword, new LogInCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        finishAndStartCardActivity();
    }
    });
}
```