# setError for TextInputLayout showing Error

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

TextInputLayout working fine, when tried to set Error it showing error.

**Code:**

```
 if (etFirstName.getText().length() == 0) {
            etFirstName.requestFocus();
            tvFirstName.setError("Please enter firstname");
        } else {
            tvFirstName.setError(null);
            tvFirstName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
```

**Check Log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:692)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:629)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:625)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:621)
            at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:297)
            at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:344)
```

Comment: setError don't work for textview. It works with editext only. To do it for textview follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508270/android-seterrorerror-not-working-in-textview

Comment: its a TextInputLayout not textview

Comment: What is tvFirstName ?

Comment: tvFirstName is TextInputLayout

Comment: @sreekanth r u try my answer?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42779409/4960501

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give valid style for your TextInputLayout(
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat")

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/testingInputLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/testingEditText"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="@string/testText"
   android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You need to add appCompat & support design dependency (if not)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

In your manifest file add AppCompat theme,

```
<application
 ...
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: It works me only change android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" for TextInputLayout, used customize theme so it not working need to check that

Comment: If you need customize theme -> use the parent theme as **Theme.AppCompat** & write your customize theme.

Comment: this part working fine in V5 onwards, how can i show same things from V4.1 onwards....theme colours only not showing properly it showing diff in V4.1 and V5 how can i make same??

Comment: use separate theme for 5 and above (values-v21 folder). below v5 use same values folder. see the answer for separate themes http://stackoverflow.com/a/32423780/3879847

Comment: How to change floating label color in below 5 @Ranjith

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108245/discussion-between-sreekanth-and-ranjith-kumar).

Answer (score 15):

Although I did not fully understand why the problem occurs, it must have to do something about how Android applies colors to Views according to its states.

Here is the way I solved the problem:

## 1) Define custom style, that will be used only for styling the errors (or hints) only:

In your `res/values/styles.xml` add new style node:

```
    <style name="error" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item> <!--apply the color you wat here -->
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    </style>
```

### 2) Apply the style to your `TextInputLayout`:

Also, make sure, that you specify `errorEnabled` attribute:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_email_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error"
    >
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                  android:hint="@string/hint_email"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Only these steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sytle theme for textinputlayout :

```
<style name="HintInputTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/input_floating_color</item>
<item name="android:textSize">22dp</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/input_floating_color</item>
</style>
<style name="InputTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textColor">#ff000000</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">#ff000000</item>
<item name="android:textSize">24dp</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#ff000000</item>
</style>

<style name="ErrorTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textColor">#ffff0000</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">#ffff0000</item>
<item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#ffff0000</item>
</style>
```

Use in Layout as :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/name_signup"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorTextAppearance"
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintInputTextAppearance"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_login"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/right_margin_login"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="@style/InputTextAppearance"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/email_signup"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorTextAppearance"
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintInputTextAppearance"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_login"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/right_margin_login"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="@style/InputTextAppearance"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**MainFragment.kt:**

```
private fun onSubmit(){
   setErrorTextField(false)

}

 private fun setErrorTextField(error: Boolean){
         if(error){
            binding.textField.isErrorEnabled = true
            binding.textField.error = "Try again!"
         }else {
            binding.textField.isErrorEnabled = false
            binding.textInputEditText.text = null
         }
}
```

**XML Layout:**

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            style="@style/Widget.Unscramble.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:hint="@string/enter_your_word"
            app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
            app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_instructions">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textNoSuggestions"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution by @Sevastyan works great for using xml layout.

However, if i have a TextInputLayout and a TextInputEditText which i created programmatically, and i did this:

```
tilCode.setErrorEnabled(true);
tilCode.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.error);
```

I will get an error. But just:

```
tilCode.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.error);
```

Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use this it never need Theme.AppCompat

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tv_metadata_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/tv_metadata_Details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use TextUtils

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etFirstName.getText().toString()))
{
   etFirstName.setError("Filed is mandatory!");
   view = etFirstName;
}
```

Comment: How this solve a problem? the editText.getText() has @NonNull which means that there is no need to check it for null, original code is valid!

Answer (score -5):

Try below code to show error in `TextInputLayout`:

```
 tvFirstName.setErrorEnabled(true);
 tvFirstName.setError("Please Enter firstName");
```