# Validating TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, validation, textview

I am making a reminder app in which the user needs to set date and time from date and time pickers. So I did the following:

```
private TextView mDateDisplay;
private TextView mTimeDisplay;
...

// Set reminder button
setButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_reminder_button);
setButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (!validate()) {
        onSetDateTimeFailed();
        return;
       }
       // creating new product in background thread
        db.addReminder(id, mEditMessageText.getText().toString(), mDateDisplay.getText().toString(), mTimeDisplay.getText().toString());
        finish();
    }
});
...

//    Validation
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String date = mDateDisplay.getText().toString();
    String time = mTimeDisplay.getText().toString();

    if (date.isEmpty() ) {
        mDateDisplay.setError("Set date");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mDateDisplay.setError(null);
    }

    if (time.isEmpty()) {
        mTimeDisplay.setError("Set time");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mTimeDisplay.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}

public void onSetDateTimeFailed() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Setting date and time failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    setButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I get is the error symbols on the textviews (!), but the only toast message I get is the *"Setting date and time failed"* and not the *"Set date"* or *"Set time"*.

The other thing I wanted to do is add a reminder message to date and time:

```
private EditText mEditMessageText;
...
//    Validation
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String message = mEditMessageText.getText().toString();

    if (message.isEmpty() || time.length() < 1 || time.length() > 140) {
        mEditMessageText.setError("Enter between 1 and 140 characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mEditMessageText.setError(null);
    }
```

But now I also get the *"Enter between 1 and 140 characters"* message when there is error in any validated field. For example, if I entered the needed number of letters in editText filed and did not select date or time I get this error message *"Enter between 1 and 140 characters"* and the error symbol (!) in editText as well.

Comment: Can you try to catch exceptions in validation? Might be an error you don't see

Comment: Try using if variable.equals("") instead of isEmpty()

Comment: @Html Tosin Tried it but I get the same result. No toast messages for "Set Date" or "Set Time" is shown, and "Enter between 1 and 140 characters" is always shown if any TextView field is empty, even if the message field itself is not empty and meets the criteria.

Comment: Use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` instead

Comment: @Vucko Like this: if (TextUtils.isEmpty(date)  )?

Comment: I guess, yes. The method takes a parameter type `CharSequence` which is any String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder etc.

Comment: @Vucko Still not working :) I get the same result.

Comment: I think the problem is in the other part of your code. Please show where you're calling `validate()` and `onSetDateTimeFailed()`

Comment: @Vucko I added it in my first code block (// Set reminder button)

Comment: I think I've found a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508270/android-seterrorerror-not-working-in-textview) check and see if it works. Setting the Error on the textview is somewhat different.

Comment: @Vucko Will try this tonight. It looks promising :) TY

Comment: @Vucko I tried adding the following: style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" to textviews in xml, and it worked (without adding a toast message), but I still get the "Enter between 1 and 140 characters" and (!) symbol if there is any empty field (either date or time field).

Comment: This is the way it should be right?

Comment: @Vucko It shows the Toast message in messageEditText even if I entered the required number of letters. It should not show (!) or the error msg if the messageEditText field is not empty. And when I add date and time the error message then dissapears from messageEditText

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116839/discussion-between-vucko-and-kemo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508270/android-seterrorerror-not-working-in-textview) helped solve setting the errors on the TextViews.

As for the other part, it was replacing `time.length()` with `message.length()`.

Just moved my most helpful comments to the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean validate() {
        String date = mDateDisplay.getText().toString();
        String time = mTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
        String message = mEditMessageText.getText().toString();

        if (date.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Set date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (time.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Set time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else if (message.isEmpty() || time.length() < 1 || time.length() > 140) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter between 1 and 140 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it and it shows messages by showing the first toast message, if I fix it it will show the second... but it does not show the (!) symbol.

Answer (score 0):

@Vucko got the answer to first part of my question - ***Why does it always show "Enter between 1 and 140 characters"***, by paying more attention to my code then I did. It was a syntax error. Instead of message.length() I wrote time.length().

For the second part of my question - ***how to show the messages for TextViews*** I found a solution on a link Vucko posted - [Android setError("error") not working in Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508270/android-seterrorerror-not-working-in-textview) by adding

```
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
```

or

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to my xml file.

TY Vucko

Comment: No problem bro. I would have liked to get some credit like accepted answer :D Can I write my own answer combining these two parts? I seek to be rewarded, it was quite a ride to find all the errors :)

Comment: @Vucko Sure thing :) Thanks again