# How to Hide Soft Keyboard on android after clicking TextView (which is set to focusable)?

Tags: android, textview, android-softkeyboard

In continuation of the answer given in
[Android setError("error") not working in Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508270/android-seterrorerror-not-working-in-textview#)
After applying the solution i.e. changing textview to focusable, A keyboard gets pop-up when that textview is clicked. How to hide that.

P.S. I tried onFocusChangeListener and onTouchListener

I want to know **where to call** this **hide keyboard** method as I tried this but it's not solving the issue;

```
    mEndTimeView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(ViewUtils.isKeyboardShown(mEndTimeView.getRootView())){
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEndTimeView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        showEndTimePicker();
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Try this answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Hi @2Dee, Here I am talking about **TextView** not **EditText**.

Answer (score 0):

You need this method to hide Soft keyboard.

```
public void closeKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Call this method to hide/close soft keyboard.

Comment: Hi Shane, I have updated the question, Please again have a look.

Comment: On which click you want to close keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
View view = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
if (view != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Call this method in button click.