# Prevent softinput that opened from first edittext to open in second edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode, soft-input-panel

I have two edittexts.

It is supposed to have this behavior.

With `addTextChangedListener` every number input from `edittext1` will be +1 and then the sum will be displayed on `edittext2`. If I input 2000 on `edittext1` then `edittext2` should then display 2001.

`edittext2` should never be able to be editted by the user using the softinput . I was able to disable the softinput from showing by using

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // API 21
        edittext2.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
    } else { // API 11-20
        edittext2.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    }
```

However, if the softinput is opened while changing `edittext1` and then the user clicks `edittext2` the softinput doesnt get hidden so the user can still enter input.

I know that using `setEnabled(false)` would solve all of my problems however, I want to the app to still be able to focus on `edittext2` to access the `setError()` message;

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so why don't you use a TextView instead?

Comment: Just a student here so this may be a silly question but, can you use setError() in TextView? And have the error message pop up when I click on it?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508270/android-seterrorerror-not-working-in-textview/15954372#15954372