# EditText.setError("Error Text") not showing popups

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, android-edittext

Im creating a simple login activity and am implementing some user input error checking on some EditText fields.

However, the setError public method seems to not show anything or, if it is, I'm unable to view when running the app.

XML for one of the EditText elements

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"

    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="#757575"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Java for error checking logic and account creation

```
public class NewUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mUserName, mUserEmail , mUserPassword, mReEnterPass;
//CardView cdCreateAcct;
Button btnCreateAcct;
TextView btnGoToLogin;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_user);

    //java variables connecting to the xml objects/resources
    mUserName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
    mUserEmail = findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
    mUserPassword =findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
    mReEnterPass=findViewById(R.id.reEnterPass);
    btnCreateAcct = findViewById(R.id.createAcctBtn);
    btnGoToLogin = findViewById(R.id.alreadyMadeAcctText);

    //instantiate the firebase variable

    //getting the current instance of database from firebase
    // to perform actions on the database
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //progress bar
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //checking if user is already logged in or account already exists

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }


    btnCreateAcct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Display a toast message
            //Toast.makeText(NewUserActivity.this, "You clicked card view ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String name = mUserName.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = mUserEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password =mUserPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String reEnterP = mReEnterPass.getText().toString().trim();

            //logic to check inputs , null , passwords the same ect.

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
                mUserName.requestFocus();
                mUserName.setError("Enter in a Username.");
                //mUserName.setError("Enter in a User Name.",);
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                mUserEmail.requestFocus();
                mUserEmail.setError("Email is Required.");
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                mUserPassword.requestFocus();
                mUserPassword.setError("Password is Required");
                return;
            }
            if (password.length() <= 8){
                mUserPassword.requestFocus();
                mUserPassword.setError("Passwords must be Greater than 8 Characters.");

            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(reEnterP)){
                mReEnterPass.requestFocus();
                mReEnterPass.setError("Passwords must be the Same.");
                return;
            }
            if((!password.equals(reEnterP))) {
                mReEnterPass.requestFocus();
                mReEnterPass.setError("Passwords must be the Same.");
                return;
            }
            //if everything is passed progress bar will show
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //create account in firebase

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(NewUserActivity.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(NewUserActivity.this, "Error !" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });



}
```

Even when clicking my Create account Button and leaving Username blank I see no error message.
[The edittext field is null and shows no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flnly.jpg)

Is my error checking logic off, or is there something wrong in my XML?

Comment: its working fine , it tried your code

Comment: create breakpoints and kindly debug , either your code reachable or not

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you could try is making your EditText focusable with 2 properties :

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Example :

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Source : [Android setError("error") not working in Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508270/android-seterrorerror-not-working-in-textview)

Comment: Still no success , is there a way to view the error logs in android studio as i press the create account button?

Comment: There is a way of logging using Logcat.
I usually use "Log.e" (error) or "Log.i" (info) for logging.
Here is documentation about it : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#java

Other than that, I'm pretty sure their is a way to find logs either in AppData or inside the emulated phone/phone you are running your application with.

Comment: Veiwing Logcat and as i click the Crete Account button i get a constant ViewPostIme pointer 0 then ViewPostIme pointer 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you only have one Activity as the launcher in you Android.manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please add some information to your answer to make it more clear.